# Making Columns inside a cell in html table

Tags: html, html-table

I have searched around and haven't found anything define. I have a lot of information that I need to put in a single cell in a table. Is there a way that I can format that cell so it has its own columns?

Something similar to this is what I'm trying to get at:

C1........   |    C2    .........| ..................C3............................|

..value...|..value... | Horse:"value"....Unicorn:"value" |

............................. | Dog:"value".......Hippie:"value".. |

............................. | Cat:"value"........Hispster:"value"|

............................. | Title:"value".......Yoga:"value"... |

............................. | T-Rex:"value"....Me:"value"...... |

---

C1........   |    C2    .........| ..................C3............................|

..value...|..value... | Horse:"value"....Unicorn:"value" |

............................. | Dog:"value".......Hippie:"value".. |

............................. | Cat:"value"........Hispster:"value"|

............................. | Title:"value".......Yoga:"value"... |

............................. | T-Rex:"value"....Me:"value"...... |

Then have it cascade down that C3 with more data specifically to that field? This shows 2 rows in the table. Sorry its very crude

Comment: Would column span work for you? Or you can also put a table within that cell.

Comment: I changed my questions to better reflect what Im looking for. Thanks for the swift responses!

Comment: I think a table within a cell would work nicely for you as long as you specify the widths of the columns of the inner table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is put another table inside that cell. The link below explains it pretty well. Basically, your code will be structured like this:

```
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="10">
<TD>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="3">
           <TD>2nd Table</TD>
           <TD>2nd Table</TD>
           <TR>
           <TD>2nd Table</TD>
           <TD>2nd Table</TD>
           </TR>
           </TABLE>
</TD>
<TD> The cell next to this one has a smaller table inside of it, a table inside a table.</TD>
</TABLE>
```

[HTML Goodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/tables/article.php/3479861/So-You-Want-A-Table-Inside-A-Table-Huh.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the response and example! Sorry for not giving much. It was kind of a "spur of the moment" idea

Answer (score -1):

If you like `table`, you can have `table` in your `table`.

Seriously: `<td> <table> <tr><td>...</td></tr> <tr><td>...</td></tr> </table> </td>`

Comment: Yea I thought of that route. But I have 10 values that i need to put in there. I guess my example was misleading